# Problem installing Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, installer, installation

I had to reinstall Windows 7 on my computer. I reinstalled everything except VS 2010.

Trying to install it, the install wizard looked like it had been corrupted. Another VS 2010 DVD however showed the same behavior.

After it's done loading components I have to click next. It then freezes after a little while. Some time later it is finished drawing the second page, yet the wizard still does not respond. When I move my mouse arrow over the window it shows a flickering loading arrow.

Trying to install VS 2008 from a DVD resulted in the exact same issue.

The only thing that has changed in my setup is that I now have 2 hard drives in RAID-0. I run the system from these drives. Could there be a problem with drivers or something? The setup.exe process is, while it's not responding, growing and growing in the memory. If I wait long enough(about 10 min.) it takes up to 450MB of memory in use.

Installing other MS products like Office, Visual Basic & C# 2010 Express, the Expression Studio 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Express worked just fine. Any ideas what  might cause this?

Comment: I'm trying to recall this step.  Does the "loading components" step happen after you've selected which portions of VS 2010 you'd like to install?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that you computer is up to date in Windows Update?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is a complex piece of software, and can get itself stuck in a strange state if installation fails any time.

I would strongly recommend you do a new fresh Windows 7 install, and take careful steps to follow a path that should lead to a successful install. Starting fresh is often much better when something strange is happening with Visual Studio any edition.

1. Fresh install Windows 7
2. Complete patch of updates, including Service Pack 1.
3. Install the .NET 4 framework prior to Visual Studio 2010 (had luck myself doing this)
4. Check for new Windows Update patches
5. Install Visual Studio 2010

Also Note: If you're installing a version of SQL Server that's not express edition, do that before Visual Studio 2010 (seems to work for me too).